# dynamic base path, up one level

Tags: php, file, path, hierarchy, radix

I have a config file that I append the $base_path variable onto.

```
$base_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

`$base_path` outputs: `/Users/username/Sites/project/Source/htdocs/`

```
$config['image_path'] = $base_path . '/uploads/images/';
```

That works great.

But I want to do the same for a directory that is one directory above the base_path

So I want to keep it dynamic without hard coding the path in, so essentially I want to dynamically create the path that is one directory above the `base_path` (the directory would be at the same level as the `htdocs` folder).

```
$config['protected_dir'] = '/Users/username/Sites/project/Source/protected_dir/';
```

How would I make that dynamic like I did with my first example (`$config['image_path']`)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your config is in the root of the basepath.

You could do this:

```
$base_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
$protected_path = realpath($base_path."/protected_dir");
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.

PS. If your config is in base_path/config/config.php you can always do this:

```
$base_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/../");
$protected_path = realpath($base_path."/protected_dir");
```

Comment: The path to the config.php file is: /Users/username/Sites/project/Source/htdocs/application/config/config.php